# Graphical operations in C++ through the JNI

Tags: java, c++, graphics, java-native-interface

I'm writing an online multiplayer game, and I'm thinking about implementing the network code in Java, using JBoss Netty. But I'm considering C++ for the 3D rendering (they're simple graphics, nothing extensive). Would it be worth implementing such behavior in C++?

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be worth implementing such behavior in C++?

No, I would recommend doing everything in java or in c++. That way you won't have any problems with c++ to java interoperability. In case you already have the network code in java I would go for that.

If you choose java you can use a 3D rendering library like for example [jogl](http://java.net/projects/jogl/) or [lwjgl](http://lwjgl.org). These libraries are really light weight and you will probably not have any problems with the actual rendering performance since it is done by the graphics chip.

Comment: @sje397: :) Updated! It was the use of two different languages I was against.

Comment: jogl has been superseeded by JSR-231.